# Cant' run an Android application with react-native [Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app']

Tags: android, react-native

I've been tasked with maintaining an old existing React Native application available on both the PlayStore and AppStore. I've cloned the repository locally and installed the necessary dependencies using **yarn install**. However, when I attempt to launch the application with **yarn android**, I encounter errors. After multiple unsuccessful attempts, I'm at a loss as to how to start my application on the Android emulator. It's worth noting that I typically work with Expo, but in this case, it's a bare React Native project, and I feel a bit lost, especially with Gradle & Android Studio tools.

When I run **npx react-native doctor**, I get the following output:

```
Android
 ✓ JDK
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 30.0.2
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME
```

Is this related to my error?

Here are the errors I encounter during **yarn android**:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
.....
```

If needed, here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "*******",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "npx android": "npx react-native run-android",
    "npx ios": "npx react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "pod": "cd ios && pod install && cd ..",
    "xcode": "open ios/******.xcworkspace",
    "studio": "open android/build.gradle",
    "postinstall": "npx pod-install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.1",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^6.1.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^12.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^12.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/functions": "^12.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^12.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^12.8.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^7.2.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "geocoder": "^0.2.3",
    "geofirex": "^0.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "performance-now": "^2.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.31.1",
    "react-native": "0.65.0",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-card-stack-swiper": "^1.2.5",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.7",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-crisp-chat-sdk": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-deck-swiper": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.7",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^8.0.5",
    "react-native-fontawesome-pro": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-gleapsdk": "^6.3.2",
    "react-native-iap": "^8.6.2",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.36.2",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.4.5",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-location": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^13.1.2",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-modals": "^0.22.3",
    "react-native-notifications": "^4.1.3",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-picker-scrollview": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-purchases": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-responsive-dimensions": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0-rc.3",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.15.0",
    "reactn": "^2.2.7",
    "rn-range-slider": "^2.1.1",
    "rn-segmented-control": "^1.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.3.0",
    "tinderswipecardsrn": "git+https://github.com/andrewvo89/tinder-swipe-cards-rn.git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.15.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.15.3",
    "@bam.tech/react-native-make": "^3.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.3",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.66.2",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried configuring Android Studio with Gradle and a JDK version matching the project, but I don't think that's sufficient. I also attempted to launch the application with **yarn android --variant:debug**, but I consistently encounter issues resulting in a BUILD FAILED. I've installed JDK 11 and set the **JAVA_HOME** variable to **C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.20.8-hotspot**.

I appreciate any guidance on what I need to do to get this application up and running. If you have any resources to recommend for learning about Gradle and related concepts, I'm eager to learn.

Thank you,
Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified your OS, so I'm assuming it's Linux.

Have you tried putting this into ~/.bashrc and then reloading the terminal?

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools
```